# Linux execute CASA from anywhere

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, path, executable

How can I start the program CASA from any directory on my Ubuntu laptop?

CASA resources: https://casa.nrao.edu/installlinux.shtml

Information is provided on 'bash' and 'path' but I am brand new to Linux use and CASA is run in terminal.

At the moment I have to navigate to the casa.../bin/ directory and type ./casa but I need to access CASA from other folders in future.

So far I have tried a multitude of combinations on the:

gedit ~/.profile &

...document but to no avail.

This document currently looks like this:

```
# if running bash
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
    # include .bashrc if it exists
    if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
    . "$HOME/.bashrc"
    fi
fi

# set PATH so it includes user's private bin directories
PATH="$PATH:/home/edited-out-name/Downloads/casa-release-4.7.2-el7/bin"

# Ubuntu make installation of Ubuntu Make binary symlink
PATH=/home/edited-out-name/.local/share/umake/bin:$PATH
```

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ooh, you are so close!  There are a couple of potential gotchas, which make a lot of sense if you know the underlying architecture of how everything fits together, but seem oddly disjointed until you do.

First, you've nailed the 'PATH' thing: any executable must exist in a directory found in the `$PATH` variable, or the shell (Bash) won't find it, failing with:

```
$ casa
casa: command not found
```

Possible gotcha: any changes you make to any environment variable do *not* get passed to programs you execute unless you specifically `export` them.  In your `~/.profile`, suggest adding `export`:

```
export PATH="$PATH:/home/edited-out-name/Downloads/casa-release-4.7.2-el7/bin"

export PATH=/home/edited-out-name/.local/share/umake/bin:$PATH
```

Possible gotcha: after you change the `~/.profile` file, your environment won't be updated until you either manually import that file:

```
$ . ~/.profile

# or alternatively
$ source ~/.profile
```

Or completely logout and log back in again.  If you're new to Linux and "want to be sure", reboot.  (Rebooting is *not* necessary, but working around your skill level, here.)

Finally, ensure that the PATH variable is what you think it should be:

```
$ echo $PATH
```

Once your PATH environment variable contains the *absolute path* to the directory with the Casa executable you want to run, this should work as you want.

Answer (score 0):

Just as an update you can now install casa using its many linux builds natively into your python environment of choice.

```
#initialize a virtual env for casa
python3 -m venv /path/to/casavenv
source /path/to/casavenv/bin/activate
pip3 install casadata casatools casatasks
```

That should get you a native python environment which supports casa and optionally any additional packages you might choose to install using pip.